# $.each не видит новые дочерние элементы, созданные во время цикла

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!
Решил попробовать сделать перемещение элементов в корзину при клике и наоборот. Но при попытке вернуть элементы из корзины в их стандартный блок, то, как я понял, `$.each` не видит новых элементов. Вот код:

```js
$(function() {
  function newBox(children, parent) {
    var newBoxMake = $('<div></div>')
      .attr('id', 'newBox')
      .insertAfter(parent)
      .css('border', '2px solid lightblue');

    $.each([children, newBoxMake.children()], function() {
      move(this);

      function move(element) {
        element.each(function() {
          $(this).click(function(e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.target.parentNode.id == parent.attr('id')) {
              $(this).remove().prependTo('#newBox');
            } else {
              $(this).remove().appendTo(parent);
            }
          });
        })
      }
    });
  }
  newBox($('#div_for_img img'), $('#div_for_img'));
});
```

```css
#newBox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_for_img">
  <img src="https://jobbroadway.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/widget-home-feature-callout-1-1.jpg" width="250px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/352770370120064299/76AC95B794CAB61D5C5459924B78E3F33518F9CD/" width="250px" height="auto">
</div>
```

Comment: почему бы не навесить обработчики сразу, зачем это делать динамически, и зачем создавать див динамически?

Comment: @teran , мне дали задание сделать динамически, и я ищу способы, как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам требуется пример реализиции перемещения изображений по клику между двумя дивами, то код будет наподобие следующего

```js
$(".img-container img").click(function(){
  var cId = $(this).closest(".img-container").attr('id');   //откуда
  var tId = cId == 'box' ? "#img-list" : "#box";            //куда  
  $(this).appendTo(tId);                                    //переместить
  
  $("#box").toggleClass("hidden", $("#box img").length == 0);  //скрыть, если пусто
});
```

```css
#img-list {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#box {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-list" class="img-container">
  <img src="https://jobbroadway.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/widget-home-feature-callout-1-1.jpg" width="250px" height="auto">
  <img src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/352770370120064299/76AC95B794CAB61D5C5459924B78E3F33518F9CD/" width="250px" height="auto">
</div>


<div id="box" class="img-container hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!